# How to get the environment mode on slim framework

Tags: php, slim

Picked from Slim Framework Documentation:

> **mode**
>
> This is an identifier for the application’s current mode of operation. The mode does not affect a Slim application’s internal functionality. Instead, the mode is only for you to optionally invoke your own code for a given mode with the **configMode()** application method.
>
> The application mode is declared during instantiation, either as an environment variable or as an argument to the Slim application constructor. It cannot be changed afterward. The mode may be anything you want — “development”, “test”, and “production” are typical, but you are free to use anything you want (e.g. “foo”).

```
<?php
  $app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'development'
  ));
?>
```

The problem is, when i try to invoke **$app->configMode();** I get a fatal error who says that the configMode() method is undefined...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access the environment mode by invoking `$app->getMode();`

Another way of doing it is using [configureMode()](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Application-Modes).

```
<?php
// Set the current mode
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'production'
));

// Only invoked if mode is "production"
$app->configureMode('production', function () use ($app) {
    $app->config(array(
        'log.enable' => true,
        'debug' => false
    ));
});

// Only invoked if mode is "development"
$app->configureMode('development', function () use ($app) {
    $app->config(array(
        'log.enable' => false,
        'debug' => true
    ));
});
```

Comment: uh oh! I didn't noticed the "Application Modes" section of the documentation, thanks!

Comment: in v3 this feature was removed - Removal of configureMode()
$app->configureMode(...) has been removed in v3

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/upgrade.html#removal-of-configuremode

Comment: $app->configureMode(...) has been removed in v3.

Answer (score 2):

Once you configure it, you can do: `$app->mode;` or `$_ENV["SLIM_MODE"];` to retrieve it.